# How to estimate the data size from a particular query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to estimate on the actual data size of a query result. For example, I want to know how big the dataset is for all records from this table that is less than 4 year old with the following query in SQL server

```
select * from dbo.MY_TABLE
where ETL_CREATE_DTM > dateadd(year, -1, getdate());
```

How exactly do I get the size of the query result, in MB or GB not the number of rows?

Comment: having sum of size of all fields multiply row count will give you an estimation

Comment: Wouldn't SELECT count(*) FROM ... give you what you want?

Comment: Client Statistics.  See eg https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/12/sql-server-management-studio-include-client-statistics-button/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft which field should I be looking at, "Bytes sent from server"? Just did two queries on the same table, first one returns 273 records and 176675300 bytes while second one returns 500 records and 169638400 bytes. It does not make sense more records have smaller byte size.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run the query, you can use the estimated query plan to get an idea of the number of rows

Just select your query in the query window, right-click and select 'Display Estimated Execution Plan'

Then if you hover your mouse over the 'SELECT' icon a popup window will show you the estimated number of rows.

[image]

You could get an idea of the amount of data by doing the following:

Right-click the table name in SSMS, and select properties, then Storage.

An estimate of the number of MB returned would be given by (Estimated Number of Rows) / (Row Count) * (Data space)

[image]

So here it would be 914/15708 * 11.266 = 0.66MB

NB This only works if you are returning entire rows, and assumes an even distribution of data in each row. This method would probably not hold up if you had binary items such as images stored in a column, but should be okay if you're just storing basic datatypes, e.g. strings, numbers.